# Permission error every time I build in visual studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, compiler-errors, unreal-engine4

I have just started learning to program using Unreal and I am following a tutorial for Unreal Engine on Udemy and recently I've been running into a problem where every time I write code wrong and I build the project , even though there are no lines indicating errors , I get this message

>

```
 1>------ Build started: Project: BuildingEscape, Configuration: Development_Editor x64 ------
1>  Compiling game modules for hot reload
1>  Performing 2 actions (2 in parallel)
1>  [2/2] Link UE4Editor-BuildingEscape-2523.lib
1>  [1/2] Link UE4Editor-BuildingEscape-7173.dll
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal Projects\03_BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UE4Editor-BuildingEscape-7173.lib and object D:\Unreal Projects\03_BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UE4Editor-BuildingEscape-7173.exp
1>     Creating library D:\Unreal Projects\03_BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UE4Editor-BuildingEscape-7173.suppressed.lib and object D:\Unreal Projects\03_BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UE4Editor-BuildingEscape-7173.suppressed.exp
1>ERROR : UBT error : Failed to produce item: D:\Unreal Projects\03_BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape\Intermediate\Build\Win64\UE4Editor\Development\UE4Editor-BuildingEscape-2523.lib
1>  Total build time: 3.07 seconds (Local executor: 0.00 seconds)
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(41,5): error MSB3075: The command ""D:\Unreal Engine\Engine\UE_4.15\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" BuildingEscapeEditor Win64 Development "D:\Unreal Projects\03_BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape.uproject" -waitmutex" exited with code 5. Please verify that you have sufficient rights to run this command.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

and even though I delete the code that I wrote and hit build again I get the same error...
I am using windows 10.

Comment: Sounds like you (among other things) have a problem with your build system not tracking dependencies correctly and thus not rebuilding all changed source files. I'd suggest fixing that problem first.

Comment: Make sure all tools required to perform the build are executable from the path you are building from.

Comment: sounds fair enough... how do I do both these things? :D

Comment: First thing you do is search on Google.

Comment: I've been looking this error up on Google for the past week , tried every solution that I've found , none worked...

Comment: Overly aggressive antivirus programs can cause problems like this too. Try disabling it or whitelisting the directory you're building in.

Comment: I've tried to disable it , still the same , I`m using the windows defender from windows 10..

Comment: Any other suggestions , please?:(

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I don't know what is causing the issue with compiling from visual studio , but if I compile using the Compile button in Unreal the code seems to be compiling just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Before you go too far down the rabbit hole, check to be sure your operating system doesn't simply have a lock on one of your intermediate files. If you delete the entire contents of D:\Unreal Projects\03_BuildingEscape\BuildingEscape\Intermediate\ before rebuilding, that will ensure that you're not simply looking at a locked or corrupt intermediate. This isn't guaranteed to be the issue, but bad intermediates can cause otherwise inexplicable build errors, so clearing them can at least narrow down the range of possible causes you'll need to investigate. Of course make sure your editor isn't running, or running as a stuck process, while you're trying to rebuild.